# How do I update MySQL table to alter my date format from Excel numeric to standard?

Tags: mysql

I used a script to insert some CSV data into my MySQL schema. The table contains about 26k records, but the dates are all in Excel numeric form-- e.g., 44890 instead of 11/25/22.

The script to update the date fields is this:

```
    DATE('1899-12-30') + INTERVAL c.Start_Date DAY AS Start_Date_c, -- converts Excel numeric date to date
    DATE('1899-12-30') + INTERVAL c.End_Date DAY AS End_Date_c, -- converts Excel numeric date to date
```

But I don't know how to incorporate this outside of a SELECT statement. I want to update the table directly in the schema, if possible.

I imagine I would do something like this:

```
     UPDATE my_table 
      SET   
        Start_Date = DATE('1899-12-30') + INTERVAL Start_Date DAY,  
        End_Date = DATE('1899-12-30') + INTERVAL End_Date DAY
```

But I'm not quite sure and don't want to risk running this and messing something up (is there a way to do a test?)... I use DataGrip if that matters.

Comment: You shouldn't trust any answer on the Web. You should always test everything first; whatever happens, you're going to need a test area. So, make a test area and test your code with example data. For example, test what happens with values 0, and 44890, etc. Perhaps even values -1 and 44890.5 *(Also, note that columns have datatypes, such as integer, date, datetime, timestamp, etc. You can't change a column's datatype with an update statement. So, create a new column with the correct datatype, and update the new column from the old column)*

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of how to update the new column from the old column?

Comment: UPDATE tbl SET x = y + z